# Labeling multiple equations like (1a-c)

Tags: subequations

I want to label two or three equations in the same line such as

x = r,  y = w                   (1a,b)

z = t,  a = q, b = p            (1c-e)

Thanks

Comment: The subequation environment lets have the 1a, 1b, etc... references. But as far as I know each equation has to be on its own line in order to have a reference.

Comment: You could use \tag{\theequation a,b} and manually \stepcounter{equation}.